# A javascript error occurred in the main process after restarting the computer

Tags: javascript, process, program-entry-point

Every time I restart my computer I am getting the following error message: [error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FuqGV.png)

I don't have any problems with my laptop but I really want to fix it. Does anyone know what could be the problem?

Thanks!

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Userfeel program tries to run `mac-screen-capture-permissions`, which is a macOS tool, on your PC.

Try uninstalling Userfeel?

Comment: Brilliant. I uninstalled it and now it's gone! thank you so much!